# How to pass the text box value as a part of href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, textbox

I try to pass text box value as a part of link `href` query string like this :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_reg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <a target="_blank" href="Schedule.aspx?nav=<%=txt_reg.Text %>" >ENTER</a>
```

---

But i get no value in `nav` parameter !

What should i do to pass the textbox value as a part of link ?

Comment: This happens cause the "txt_rag" is empty at load.
You should use client-side code (ie. Javascript) to update the href property on the client..

Comment: @llouk : i write a number in the textbox then clicking on the link

Comment: yes, I got it.. "<% %>" are server tags. The code inside it is runs only at load. And if at load the textBox is empty, it will output an empty string inside href. You should try looking for a solution using Javascript on that.

Comment: @llouk Do You have any idea , how to do it client side please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type=text id=txt_reg />

 <a target="_blank" href="" onclick="this.href='Schedule.aspx?nav='+document.getElementById('txt_reg').value" >ENTER</a>
```

Comment: Nice and simple answer. The only downside is that on hover the link will not be visible to the browser tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_reg" onchange="UpdateLink();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <a id="myLnk" target="_blank" href="Schedule.aspx?nav=" >ENTER</a>

<script>
function UpdateLink()
{
    var NavValue = document.getElementById("<%=txt_reg.ClientID%>").value;
    document.getElementById("myLnk").href = "Schedule.aspx?nav=" + NavValue;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code for setting value to href

$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txt_reg").change(function () {

            $("a").attr("href","test.com?=" +$(this).val());
        });
    });